# The fourth and fifth

Tags: articles

What is the difference in the meaning of the following two sentences

> I can't do **the fourth and fifth** questions but I have done all the others.
>
> I can't do **the fourth and the fifth** questions but I have done all the others.

Is anyone of them ungrammatical?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The first and (the) second chapter(s) are difficult - which is correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/134484/the-first-and-the-second-chapters-are-difficult-which-is-correct) Also (and perhaps better), [How to use article 'the' with conjunction?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/99590/how-to-use-article-the-with-conjunction)

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is correct. We don’t need to add a second “the” in the second sentence. However, the following version is also correct if you want to add a second “the”:

> I can't do the fourth question and the fifth question but I have done all the others.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you did not answer questions not deemed high quality by the community. Answering off-topic or low-quality questions encourages users to ask more of them in the future. Please see discussion on meta [DO NOT FEED THE BEARS](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/do-not-feed-the-bears) [Stop answering close-worthy questions!](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/stop-answering-close-worthy-questions/2966#2966)